# ListBox doesn't refresh when listBoxItem is deleted in c#

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8.1, observablecollection

How to refresh UserInterface when a listbox item is deleted from ListBox.The ListBoxItem is getting deleted from database, but the listbox is not getting refreshed. When I press the backbutton and navigating to the page it is deleted.Can anyone tell me how to refresh listbox. I think it is due to observable collection,I don't know how to implement NotifyProperty changed for this code.Can anyone help me please?

> C# code to insert,read and delete items from database

```
 public class DatabaseHelperClass
{

    SQLiteConnection dbConn;

    //Create Tabble 
    public async Task<bool> onCreate(string DB_PATH)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!CheckFileExists(DB_PATH).Result)
            {
                using (dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
                {
                    dbConn.CreateTable<Data>();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private async Task<bool> CheckFileExists(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var store = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            return true;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException exp)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Retrieve the specific contact from the database. 
    public Data ReadContact(int contactid)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existingconact = dbConn.Query<Data>("select * from Contacts where Id =" + contactid).FirstOrDefault();
            return existingconact;
        }
    }
    // Retrieve the all contact list from the database. 
    public ObservableCollection<Data> ReadContacts()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            List<Data> myCollection = dbConn.Table<Data>().ToList<Data>();
            ObservableCollection<Data> ContactsList = new ObservableCollection<Data>(myCollection);

            return ContactsList;
        }

}


    // Insert the new contact in the Contacts table. 
    public void Insert(Data newcontact)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
                dbConn.Insert(newcontact);
            });
        }
    }

    //Delete specific contact 
    public void DeleteContact(int Id)
    {
         using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            var existingconact = dbConn.Query<Data>("select * from Data where Id =" + Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existingconact != null)
            {
                dbConn.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    dbConn.Delete(existingconact);
                });
            }
        }
    }
    //Delete all contactlist or delete Contacts table 
    public void DeleteAllContact()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
        {
            //dbConn.RunInTransaction(() => 
            //   { 
            dbConn.DropTable<Data>();
            dbConn.CreateTable<Data>();
            dbConn.Dispose();
            dbConn.Close();
            //}); 
        }
    }
}
```

> Code to delete item from list.

```
 public partial class Panaroma : Page
{
    ObservableCollection<Data> DB_ContactList = new ObservableCollection<Data>();


    public Panaroma()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        if(listBoxobj.Items.Count == 0)
        {
            Btn_Delete.IsEnabled = false;
        }


        this.Loaded += Panaroma_Loaded;

    }

    private void Panaroma_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAllData dbcontacts = new ReadAllData();

        DB_ContactList = dbcontacts.GetAllContacts();//Get all DB contacts 
        if (DB_ContactList.Count > 0)
        {
            Btn_Delete.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        listBoxobj.ItemsSource = DB_ContactList.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();//Binding DB data to LISTBOX and Latest contact ID can Display first.

    }


    private void listBoxobj_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int SelectedContactID = 0;
        if (listBoxobj.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            Data listitem = listBoxobj.SelectedItem as Data;//Get slected listbox item 
            DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
            Db_Helper.DeleteContact(listitem.Id);//Delete selected DB contact Id.
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are only deleting the selected item from the database. Also you should delete it from the collection and refresh the collection. For the implementation of the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface, there are a few good examples here at SO.

Comment: Hi @Ben,How to delete the selected item from collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove an item from the Collection, use the method `Remove` (listitem) [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.110).aspx) and update the related ListBox.

```
private void listBoxobj_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int SelectedContactID = 0;
    if (listBoxobj.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        Data listitem = listBoxobj.SelectedItem as Data;//Get slected listbox item 
        DatabaseHelperClass Db_Helper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
        Db_Helper.DeleteContact(listitem.Id);//Delete selected DB contact Id.
        //remove item from collection
        DB_ContactList.Remove(listitem); 
        //update listbox
        //...
    }
}
```

To update the ListBox have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705100/windows-phone-listbox-itemssource)